# windows tool to view website client content without browser

Tags: html, windows, web-crawler

Per the title, I am looking for a tool or some sort of initiative that's already been undertaken by other developers to simply grab data off of websites so one can navigate them without looking at them in the browser.  I am fully aware of how most pages work so what I would like to do is just look at the data that's being pulled from them per windows technology that's already (hopefully) been written.  Does this make sense?  Here is an example of what I would like to see in a tool:

- a windows interface that gives me data about a webpage (menus, submenus,
  button names/captions, etc...
- be able to execute transactions on those pages by specifying what to do
  through the tool's interface (click button, download image, etc..)

does anyone know of a tool out there to do such things?

Answer (score 0):

The closest "program" that comes to mind is

[`WWW::Mechanize`](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm)

Advertised as

> Handy web browsing in a Perl object

This can in fact be used on Windows, however you
[will need Perl](http://strawberryperl.com).

Comment: thanks!  this file is probably very useful: http://search.cpan.org/~mstrout/WWW-Mechanize-1.72_02/bin/mech-dump

do you know any other tools?  that is an OK tool, but it would have to be severely modified in order to get what I'm envisioning...